# ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(procedure.description[0].answer) | limitTo:100" limitto is not working with ng-html-bind

Tags: angularjs, javascript-objects

```
 ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(procedure.description[0].answer)
|limitTo:100"

$scope.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml;
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1. trustAsHtml is not a function in your code. so you cant pass parameters
2. set

$scope.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(procedure.description[0].answer);

```
 ng-bind-html= "trustAsHtml|limitTo:100"
```

use this link : http://jsfiddle.net/4x6z283a/1/